# Cereal serialization

Tags: c++, c++11, serialization, cereal

I have a problem in C++11 with cereal (http://uscilab.github.io/cereal/).

I have a shared library, and I would like to serialize one of its classes using cereal library. Here is a part of the code of the library "I would like to serialize Object class":

"Object.hpp"

```
class ObjectPrivate;

class Object
{
 public:
    ...
    template <class Archive>
    void load(Archive& archive);

    template <class Archive>
    void save(Archive& archive) const;

 protected: 
    std::unique_ptr<ObjectPrivate> d_ptr;
};

template<>
void Object::load<cereal::BinaryInputArchive>(cereal::BinaryInputArchive& archive);

template<>
void Object::save<cereal::BinaryOutputArchive>(cereal::BinaryOutputArchive& archive) const;
```

"Object.cpp"

```
#include"Object_p.hpp"
template <class Archive>
void Object::load(Archive& archive)
{
    archive(d_ptr);
}

template <class Archive>
void Object::save(Archive& archive) const
{
    archive(d_ptr);
}
```

"Object_p.hpp"

```
#include"Object.hpp"

class ObjectPrivate
{
 public:
    int m_id;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar)
    {
        ar(m_id);
    }
};
```

but I got an error:

```
error: undefined reference to void GraphicalObject::save<cereal::BinaryOutputArchive>(cereal::BinaryOutputArchive&) const
error: undefined reference to void GraphicalObject::load<cereal::BinaryInputArchive>(cereal::BinaryInputArchive&)
```

Comment: Can we use cereal to Deserialize an XML Schema to C++ object??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CS Pei is right, I forgot the implementation of the functions:

```
template<>
void Object::load<cereal::BinaryInputArchive>(cereal::BinaryInputArchive& archive);

template<>
void Object::save<cereal::BinaryOutputArchive>(cereal::BinaryOutputArchive& archive) const;
```

The right implementation:

"Object.hpp"

```
class ObjectPrivate;

class Object
{
 public:
    ...
    template <class Archive>
    void load(Archive& archive);

    template <class Archive>
    void save(Archive& archive) const;

 protected: 
    std::unique_ptr<ObjectPrivate> d_ptr;
};

template<>
void Object::load<cereal::BinaryInputArchive>(cereal::BinaryInputArchive& archive);

template<>
void Object::save<cereal::BinaryOutputArchive>(cereal::BinaryOutputArchive& archive) const;
```

"Object.cpp"

```
#include"Object_p.hpp"
template <class Archive>
void Object::load(Archive& archive)
{
    archive(d_ptr->m_id);
}

template <class Archive>
void Object::save(Archive& archive) const
{
    archive(d_ptr->m_id);
}

template <>
void GraphicalObject::save<cereal::BinaryOutputArchive>(cereal::BinaryOutputArchive& archive) const
{
    archive(d_ptr->m_id);
}

template <>
void GraphicalObject::load<cereal::BinaryInputArchive>(cereal::BinaryInputArchive& archive)
{
    archive(d_ptr->m_id);
}
```

"Object_p.hpp"

```
#include"Object.hpp"

class ObjectPrivate
{
 public:
    int m_id;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You declared two specializations of the templates,

```
template<>
void Object::load<cereal::BinaryInputArchive>(cereal::BinaryInputArchive&     archive);

template<>
void Object::save<cereal::BinaryOutputArchive>(cereal::BinaryOutputArchive& archive) const;
```

but you forgot to implement them.

Comment: you are partially right. also the serialization function in the class ObjectPrivate should be omitted, and the save load function in the class Object should be like
  template <class Archive>
void Object::load(Archive& archive)
{
    archive(d_ptr->m_id);
}

template <class Archive>
void Object::save(Archive& archive) const
{
    archive(d_ptr->m_id);
}